# ASP.NET MVC's AsyncController and Session data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

We have a somewhat complex and long-running action method for which we'd like to show a progress bar.  The javascript grid that we're using requires that saving and loading data be done in a single request (save first then load), and also requires us saving data to session.

Our initial thought was to just use an AsyncController, but the method obviously failed since it accesses (and saves to) session state.  Since we cannot split up the action due to the javascript grid, is there any other option?

Comment: i may have misread this the first time.  must the method update the session on completion?

Comment: @dove - correct.  The grid needs to know the total # of columns/rows (calculated on load), which is stored in the session so that we don't need to reload the entire grid every time we change a column width.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service bus and send a message to this.  Granted this might be overkill for what you are doing but could be worth a look.

Search SO for rhinobus, masstransit or nservicebus.   These would allow you to send a message asynchronously but you have to setup the application that subscribes to this message.